# Database modeling Playlists with Songs

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I am trying to figure out the logic of setting up models for a `Playlist` and `Song`.

So far I have:

`User has_many :playlists, has_many :songs`

`Playlist belongs_to :user, has_many :songs`

`Song belongs_to :user`

I'm not sure how I should go about associating that a Song can belong to many Playlists.

Would I want to setup a `has_and_belongs_to_many :playlists` and setup a join table or should I do a `has_many :through` association?

Can you do a HABTM association on just one model or does it have to be declared on the two models you're relating? It doesn't sound right to have a `has_and_belongs_to_many :songs` association on the `Playlist` model.

The relationship between `User` and `Song` works fine, I'm just trying to implement `Playlist`. Of course, a song does not have to belong to a playlist.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One would normally have a table with the following structure:

```
unique_id song_id playlist_id
```

This allows for any number of songs to belong to any number of playlists. The unique_id is just for the row in your new table.

Comment: So I wouldn't need a join table/has_many :through? And would I only declare the HABTM association on the Song model?

Comment: One Song can 'belong to' (be related to) many Playlists. One Playlist can 'belong to' (be related to) many Songs. So, it seems you'd want to declare the HABTM assocation on both models. I believe 'has_many :through' is only needed if you want extra columns, such a rating for playlist/song pair (e.g. this song is great for this playlist).

Comment: Thank you for the clarification. I guess seeing 'belong_to' as relating to makes more sense in the context of a Playlist belonging to a Song.

Comment: No problem, with many-many relationships the concept of 'ownership' is often fuzzy.

Answer (score 2):

While HABTM will totally work I think you'll want to use has_many :through because you'll most likely want to add some extra information to the list/song relationship model. For example, song position.

Something like:

```
List
  belongs_to :user
  has_many :relationships
  has_many :songs, :through => relationships

Song
  belongs_to :user
  has_many :relationships
  has_many lists, :through => :relationships

Relationship
  belongs_to :song
  belongs_to :list
```

Answer (score 0):

How about this.

```
User:
  has_many :lists 
  has_many :songs

List: 
  belongs_to :user
  has_and_belongs_to_many :songs

Song
  belongs_to :user
  has_and_belongs_to_many :lists
```